Node PG Insertion failure missing two field with all provided data
Conext

I have a table storing notes in a table
This notes first run through Google KMS for encryption
Google KMS returns back to me the encrypted buffer
Then I try storing into the table

Issues

When running the insertion query I get the exception below

error: wrong number of columns: 170131690, expected 2
at /Users/<username>/Projects/<project name>/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:526:17
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  length: 133,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42804',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: 'unnamed portal parameter $4',
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'rowtypes.c',
  line: '557',
  routine: 'record_recv'
}

Code Implementation
Notes Table
CREATE TABLE Notes (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  faculty VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  level VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  module VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  paper bytea_or_text NOT NULL,
  release_date DATE NOT NULL,
  shared_with INTEGER[],
  approved_by INTEGER[],
  required_approvals INTEGER[],
  rejections INTEGER[],
  feedback TEXT[],
  created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  author INTEGER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_author FOREIGN KEY (author) REFERENCES Account(id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);


Function where insertion breaks
  public create = async (data: NotesrCreation, author: number) => {
    try {
      const client = await this.pool.connect();
      const query: QueryConfig = {
        name: 'save-assessment-paper',
        text: 'INSERT INTO Notes (faculty, level, module, paper, author, release_date, name) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7)',
        values: [data.faculty, data.level, data.module, data.paper, author, data.release_date, data.name],
      };
      const queryResponse = (await client.query<NotePaper>(query)).rows[0];
      client.release();
      return queryResponse;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Notes.model - 28`, error);
      throw new AppError(
        EErrorMessage.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
        EStatusCode.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
        false,
        'Failed to save notes paper'
      );
    }
  };

